# Automating HTML font embedding PHP backend

Tags: php, html, fonts, font-face

I understand that css3.0 supports the Font-Face tag, correctly in the latest Opera, Safari, and Firefox browsers, but that Internet Explorer still requires the microsoft .eot format.

Is there a reliable way to generate an eot file server side from a .ttf given that the hosting server may not be Windows?

I need the entire process automated, to provide a bit of background it is a print product website, part of the process involves designers building templates and uploading fonts for printable products, some of these have editable regions which are rendered to a customer as HTML form elements, however without providing the font it is impossible to provide an accurate real-time preview of the edit.

Flash and Javascript techniques wont work as the text is in a textarea or text input field and has to remain editable.

So I need a Font-Face linking to the ttf file for compatible browsers, and something else for i.e  The question is, how to automate that something else for i.e.

Thanks

Comment: Removed "embedded" tag as this isn't about embedded programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EOT files are a strange format. They are supposed to be locked down to a certain domain, to prevent copying, and the original conversion app is old and barely functioning.

The only way I can think of to automate TTF->EOT is to use the command line program ttf2eot found [here](http://code.google.com/p/ttf2eot/). In PHP, you can use the function system() to run command line programs, assuming that your web host allows it.

I hope that helps you.